# How do I update Pop!_OS from 20.04 to 20.10

Tags: apt, upgrade, software-updates, pop-os, dist-upgrade

When I try to run an upgrade of pop in the terminal (current version 21.04) I get the following:

```
$ pop-upgrade release upgrade
checking if pop-upgrade requires an update
Current Release: 21.04
Upgrading to: 21.10
New version available: 3
Event: updating package lists
Release upgrade status: release upgrade aborted: failed to update package lists for the current release
pop-upgrade: calling ReleaseUpgradeFinalize method failed
  caused by: release upgrade cannot be finalized, because a release upgrade was not performed
```

If this is relevant, this is the output of `apt update`:

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary hirsute InRelease
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease
Ign:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse Sources
Ign:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main Sources
Ign:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe Sources
Ign:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/restricted Sources
Ign:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main Translation-en
Ign:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/restricted Translation-en
Ign:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe i386 Packages
Ign:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe Translation-en
Ign:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:22 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse Sources [8,384 B]
Err:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse Sources
  File has unexpected size (285412 != 8384). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:8384 [weak]
   - SHA256:7b5f54f035a24fca10c1c1b7681608fdd15cce4eac6d52bdf872f3c761321588
   - SHA1:9bde5b972ad5ac48d1fa6907369a8178af4cd215 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:3ab7612fe313c20f8f924c325acbb5c8 [weak]
  Release file created at: Wed, 20 Oct 2021 15:04:19 +0000
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main Sources [147 kB]
Err:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main Sources
  
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe Sources [40.8 kB]
Err:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe Sources
  
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/restricted Sources [13.5 kB]
Err:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/restricted Sources
  
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages [201 kB]
Err:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages
  
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main Translation-en [107 kB]
Err:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main Translation-en
  
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [7,704 B]
Err:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
  
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/restricted i386 Packages [19.7 kB]
Err:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/restricted i386 Packages
  
Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/restricted amd64 Packages [211 kB]
Err:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/restricted amd64 Packages
  
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/restricted Translation-en [29.6 kB]
Err:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/restricted Translation-en
  
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [480 B]
Err:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata
  
Hit:25 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu groovy InRelease
Hit:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Hit:27 http://deb.playonlinux.com cosmic InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                        
Hit:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lubomir-brindza/nautilus-typeahead/ubuntu hirsute InRelease                                                                                                                                               
Hit:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu hirsute InRelease                                                                                                                                                               
Hit:30 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                               
Hit:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/release/ubuntu hirsute InRelease                                                                                                                                                                
Hit:32 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                          
Hit:33 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                     
Hit:34 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu hirsute InRelease                                                                                                                                                                     
Hit:35 http://ppa.launchpad.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable/ubuntu hirsute InRelease                                                                                                                                              
Hit:36 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/21.04/prod hirsute InRelease                                                                                                                       
Hit:37 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu hirsute InRelease                                             
Hit:38 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                              
Hit:39 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal InRelease                                
Hit:40 http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable InRelease                        
Ign:41 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/release/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
Ign:42 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/release/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages
Ign:43 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/release/ubuntu hirsute/main Translation-en
Ign:44 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/release/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:45 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/release/ubuntu hirsute/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons
Ign:46 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/release/ubuntu hirsute/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:47 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/release/ubuntu hirsute/main DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons
Ign:48 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/release/ubuntu hirsute/main DEP-11 128x128 Icons
Ign:49 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/release/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Get:41 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/release/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages [404 kB]
Err:41 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/release/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
  File has unexpected size (32 != 404352). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::19 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:404352 [weak]
   - SHA256:63c65e415ae639ec1f1887184661baa5c358222f805fc7b330b1719c012ea9c9
   - SHA1:48ede0e138e2c6b8d80471daad6327224985ff14 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:fc14e07ca9d5a4b47bdac3179aea4c80 [weak]
  Release file created at: Wed, 20 Oct 2021 15:04:19 +0000
Get:42 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/release/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages [201 kB]
Err:42 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/release/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages
  
Get:43 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/release/ubuntu hirsute/main Translation-en [107 kB]
Err:43 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/release/ubuntu hirsute/main Translation-en
  
Ign:44 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/release/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:45 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/release/ubuntu hirsute/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons
Ign:46 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/release/ubuntu hirsute/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:47 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/release/ubuntu hirsute/main DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons
Ign:48 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/release/ubuntu hirsute/main DEP-11 128x128 Icons
Ign:49 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/release/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages', as repository 'https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hirsute/multiverse/source/Sources.xz  File has unexpected size (285412 != 8384). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:8384 [weak]
    - SHA256:7b5f54f035a24fca10c1c1b7681608fdd15cce4eac6d52bdf872f3c761321588
    - SHA1:9bde5b972ad5ac48d1fa6907369a8178af4cd215 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:3ab7612fe313c20f8f924c325acbb5c8 [weak]
   Release file created at: Wed, 20 Oct 2021 15:04:19 +0000
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hirsute/main/source/Sources.xz  
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hirsute/universe/source/Sources.xz  
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hirsute/restricted/source/Sources.xz  
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hirsute/main/binary-i386/Packages.xz  
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hirsute/main/i18n/Translation-en.xz  
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hirsute/main/cnf/Commands-amd64.xz  
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hirsute/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.xz  
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hirsute/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages.xz  
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hirsute/restricted/i18n/Translation-en.xz  
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hirsute/restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64.xz  
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/release/ubuntu/dists/hirsute/main/binary-amd64/Packages.xz  File has unexpected size (32 != 404352). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::19 80]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:404352 [weak]
    - SHA256:63c65e415ae639ec1f1887184661baa5c358222f805fc7b330b1719c012ea9c9
    - SHA1:48ede0e138e2c6b8d80471daad6327224985ff14 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:fc14e07ca9d5a4b47bdac3179aea4c80 [weak]
   Release file created at: Wed, 20 Oct 2021 15:04:19 +0000
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/release/ubuntu/dists/hirsute/main/binary-i386/Packages.xz  
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/release/ubuntu/dists/hirsute/main/i18n/Translation-en.xz  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Try again - the server **may** have been only partially updated with 21.10

Comment: Still doesn't work, same error as in the post.